# Corvallis 1979 proceedings

Tags: automorphic-forms, nt.number-theory, l-functions

These proceedings have long been freely available on the AMS website, but now it seems we can't even find them anymore (e.g. http://www.ams.org/publications/online-books/pspum331-index and http://www.ams.org/publications/online-books/pspum332-index). Unfortunately, I don't own a copy, nor have I ever downloaded it on my computer. My question, then: Does anyone know if there exists another website where I could get it?

Comment: The question is : under what licence was it freely available? I do have a copy, but...

Comment: Maxime, I learned from an nLab colleague that the AMS is in the process of reorganizing their website, and now many hundreds of links have been rendered dysfunctional. You might write the AMS Webmaster to register your complaint/observation. Hopefully, if enough people cry out, they will fix the problem. 

Comment: These proceedings are available here: http://ifile.it/9nmpd0

Comment: I always check http://library.nu/ first.

Comment: Now it is always available at genesis library.

Comment: The AMS pages for these books are now http://www.ams.org/books/pspum/033.1 and http://www.ams.org/books/pspum/033.2; however they no longer seem to be freely available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the importance of the proceedings, I leave a link to the copy at Library Genesis:

A. Borel and W. Casselman (Editors) [Automorphic Forms, Representations and L-functions](http://libgen.in/get.php?md5=B528264153CDDD8461BE1CC50CE4000F) (1979)